# Generate a Secret Number and Guess it in C

Tags: c, pointers

So a little background, I have to create a program in which you generate a secret number, the user has to input a three digit number as a guess and the program should print hints along the way. Hints are print "fermi" if you have a digit in the correct place, print "pico" if you have a correct digit but not in the correct place and then print "bagels" if nothing matches. The issue I'm having is I keep getting an error or a warning message "makes integer from pointer without a cast" i assume I'm not passing pointers correctly into my function, so if anyone could help me out that would be greatly appreciated.

```
int main()
{
    setvbuf(stdout, NULL, _IONBF, 0);
    srand((int)time(NULL));
    play_game();
}

void play_game()
{
    int *num1 = 0;
    int *num2 = 0;
    int *num3 = 0;
    int guess,first,second,third, x;
    theSame(&num1, &num2, &num3);
    do
    {
        printf("\nPlease enter a three digit number as your guess or enter 0 to exit: ");
        x = scanf("%d", &guess);
        if(!x == 0)
        {
            first = guess/ 100;
            second = (guess%100) /10;
            third = guess %10;
            printf("Guess: %d, ", guess); print_hint(guess, num1,num2,num3);
            is_guess_correct(guess, num1, num2, num3);
        }

    }
    while((!x == 0));
}

void generate_secret_number(int *a, int *b, int *c)
{
    *a = (rand() % 9) + 1;
    *b = (rand() % 10);
    *c = (rand() % 10);
} 

int is_guess_correct(int guess, int a, int b, int c)
{
    int first, second, third;
    first = guess/ 100;
    second = (guess%100) /10;
    third = guess %10;

    if (first == a && second == b && third == c)
    {
        return 1;
    }
    else
    {
        return 0;
    }
}

void print_hint(int guess, int a, int b, int c)
{
    int first, second, third;
    first = guess/ 100;
    second = (guess%100) /10;
    third = guess %10;

    if (a == first || b == second || c == third)
    {
        printf("Fermi, ");
    }
if (first == b || first == c || second == a || second == c || third == a || third == b)
    {
        printf("Pico, ");
    }
    if (a == first && b == second && c == third)
    {
        printf("Winner !!");
    }
    else if(a != first && b != second && c!= third)
    {
        printf("Bagels");
    }
}

void theSame(int *a, int *b, int *c)
{
    generate_secret_number(a,b,c);
    while(*a == *b || *b == *c || *c == *a)
    {
        if (*a == *b)
        {
            *a = (rand() % 8) + 1;
        }
        if (*b == *c)
        {
            *b = (rand() % 9);
        }
        if (*a == *c)
        {
            *c = (rand() % 9);
        }
    }
    printf("\nsecret number: %d%d%d", *a,*b,*c);
}
```

Comment: The error has a line number associated with it; share it here.  Always include complete error messages; don't paraphrase.  The details are important.

Comment: I expect you need to print one Fermi per correct digit and one Pico per out-of-place digit, not just print once them once if there are any? That's how [Mastermind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mastermind_(board_game)) usually works.

Answer (score 2):

```
int *num1 = 0;
int *num2 = 0;
int *num3 = 0;
```

I think this is not what you want. You declare 3 pointers pointing to `0` there is no memory allocated and and later on you pass the address of the pointer to `void theSame(int *a, int *b, int *c)`.
Maybe you want to remove the `*` from the declaration, then you declare normal variables and when you pass the address of them to the function you use the correct interface.

If you declare `numX`as integers instead of pointers all your other interfaces are also used correctly. So use this instead:

```
int num1 = 0;
int num2 = 0;
int num3 = 0;
```

---

You should also declare your functions before you use them, so you should either use forward declaration (recommended) or copy the functions at the beginning of the file.

---

As a sidenote if you activate warnings with `-Wall` you would see that `int first, second, third` are not used in `play_game()`

Answer (score 1):

There are two main issues with your pointer handling:
The function call of `the_same` requires pointers to intbut you are passing the address of the pointers.

The second problem is, the call of `is_guess_correct` and the call to `print_hint`. It requires three Integers but you are passing the pointers and not their values.

The solution is to replace the declaration of the pointers with integers. Then you are passing the Address of the variables to `the_same` and the values to the other functions.